# Running a specific test determined at run time

Tags: python, testing, testcomplete

I have a project suite that I am using to test a x86 and x64 bit software. I need to test some parts of the software when its x86 and not test some when it is x64. I already have some scripts that determine the bitness of the software it is currently testing.

My question is mainly to see if there is a way that I can run a specific script/test only if its the correct bitness.

My current structure of my project suite:

- Folder containing tests

  - A few child tests
  - Folder with child tests
  - Folder with child tests <--- Only want to run these tests if  x86
  - Folder with child tests
  - etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you manually calling these tests?

Comment: They grouped together in folders and the tests run in order down the tree. It is just a collection of scripts/functions it calls

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly but...Can it be as simple as checking an env variable?

```
# Code above the main block
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.environ["DOTEST_THIS_SUBFOLDER"]:
        # Tests
```

Or an arg passed to the script by the caller?

```
# Code above the main block
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == "arbitrary":
        # Tests
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [check the needed bitness](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-Functional-Web/Checking-if-the-test-is-running-on-64-bit-system-or-not/m-p/71699#M11887) via the OSInfo.Windows64bit property and [run the test](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-General-Discussions/How-should-I-call-a-TestComplete-script-at-runtime/m-p/90512#M17932) by using the eval function.